# What does ～たでえ mean?

Tags: words

Here is the sentences including the words said by a Kansai guy.

思{おも}ったよりやるやないか。ええ？

見｛み｝なおし**たでえ**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

「で」is the Kansai equivalent of 「よ」, so it's 「見なおした」+「で」

見なおしたで～ is the same as 見なおしたよ

(the で　sound is often extended in speech, that's why there's an え on the end. Same as using「～」)